# How to indent c++ "special" source lines that don't end with semicolons

Tags: indentation, c++, cc-mode

I'm working with a system that uses special macros a lot. For instance:

`class UDSSLib : public UFunctionLibrary
{
  GENERATED_BODY()
  void foo();
  int i;
}`

The problem is the `GENERATED_BODY()` line. It's not supposed to have a semicolon after it (I guess the macro expansion has that) and I'd like to stick to that style, but as is, everything after it gets indented too far -- as `statement-cont` syntax rather than `statement`.
Can I either convince the C syntax analyzer that the specific string `GENERATED_BODY()` is a complete statement, or else cause the line after it to be indented normally?

Comment: see http://blog.binchen.org/posts/ccjava-code-indentation-in-emacs.html

Comment: That article covers some of the basics of c-mode indentation; I understand all that (I'm a fairly advanced emacs-lisp hacker). This is a special and a bit unusual case and that article didn't cover it, unless I missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with `GENERATED_BODY()` from UnrealEngine and so found your question.

What works for me is to [add to the buffer-local variable `c-macro-names-with-semicolon` and then call the function `c-make-macro-with-semi-re`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Macros-with-_003b.html).

For example:

```
(defun add-c++-macro-names-with-semicolon ()
  (add-to-list 'c-macro-names-with-semicolon "GENERATED_BODY")
  (c-make-macro-with-semi-re))
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'add-c++-macro-names-with-semicolon)
```

Additional search terms:
CompilerResultsLog: Error:
Extra ';' before
semicolon